# Get the django object backward using foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models using Django Framework:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()
class Group(models.Model):
    groupId = models.AutoField()
    name = models.CharField()
    students = models.ForeignKey(Student)
class Faculty(models.Model):
    facultyId = models.AutoField()
    students = models.ForeignKey(Student)
```

I need to get the list of all students and for each one to have the student's group and faculty.

Comment: try this `result = Student.objects.values('name', 'group__name', 'faculty__facultyId')`

Comment: yes, it's ok, but I have 20 field for each model and it's not so nice to write it manually, I think there should me an automatic method to get this data

Comment: I think you should use `ModelSerializer` , http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Are you creating framework or normal?

Comment: I'm using Django framework without  any changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you need to modify your model relationships. With your current models, each Faculty and Group will have a single student.
You can modify the model to this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    groupId = models.AutoField()
    name = models.CharField()

class Faculty(models.Model):
    facultyId = models.AutoField()

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    faculty = models.ForeighKey(Faculty)
```

Then to get the Group and faculty of each student you can use `select_related`.
Now your query will look like this:

```
Students.objects.all().select_related('group', 'faculty')
```

Comment: ok, but in case if I have a Product model, Translation and Variante, Translation and Variante have foreign key for product, how can I get the list of products?

Comment: What is the structure of the Translation and Variante Models?

Comment: class Variante(models.Model):
    var_id = models.AutoField()
    pro = models.ForeignKey(Prodotto)
    var_ord = models.IntegerField()
    var_nome = models.CharField()
    var_cod = models.CharField()
    var_price = models.FloatField()

class Translation(models.Model):
    trad_id = models.AutoField()
    pro = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    lang_id = models.IntegerField()
    trad_title = models.CharField()
    trad_meta = models.TextField()
    trad_desc = models.CharField()

Comment: From your models,looks like  one instance of Translation is linked to a single Product, and the same applies to the Variante model... But a Product can have more than one instances of Variante as well as Translation linked to it. Is that the desired scenario?

Comment: In that case your query will be:

`Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('variante_set', 'translation_set')`

That will give you a list of products with the related `Variante` and `Translation` objects

For each Product item you can the the related Variante and Translation objects usint `item.variante_set.all()` and `item.translation_set.all()`

Comment: Edit: you can ***get** the related ... objects ***using**

Comment: ok, and how is possible to save the item.variante_set.all() and item.translation_set.all() in each product object and return this list in JsonResponse?

Comment: To return the list as JSON can use `JsonResponse` from the `django.http` package. First specify the fields to get from the database, replacing `product_field` and `another_product_field` with the fields you want to fetch for the Product model i.e 

`products = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('variante_set', 'translation_set').values('product_field', 'another_product_field', 'variante', 'translation')`

then `return JsonResponse({'products': products})`

Comment: ok, but in this case, variante and translation return me just the id of them, not all the data of them :(

Comment: To access other fields of the `Product` and `Variante` model, you have to loop through the Product items, building a dictionary which you can then convert it to a JSON object
You can view an example using this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IxJEOZL9UjeIgpdrg1NwzGyIiVrHeO6i/view?usp=sharing), assuming your Product model has a `name` attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()
     surname = models.CharField()
class Group(models.Model):
     groupId = models.AutoField()
     name = models.CharField()
     students = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name="group")
class Faculty(models.Model):
    facultyId = models.AutoField()
    students = models.ForeignKey(Student, "related_name"="faculty")
```

you can get this data Student.objects.filter(group__isnull=False, faculty__isnull=False )

It will return the student who have faculty and group.

for Json data:

```
class Student(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Student
       fields = ('name', 'surname' , 'group', 'faculty')
```

Comment: this returns me the Studets data, without data about group and faculty

Comment: you will get the list of student object and from student object you can access the group and faculty data. Ex- if std1 is one student object. std1.group.all() will return and std1.faculty.all()

Comment: yes, you are right, but how can I return this data as a JsonResponse?

Comment: you can create the serializer.